# Publication information on "Recreational Mathematics Magazine"

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

I'm currently studying Martin Gardner's 1968 repackaging of two of Henry Ernest Dudeney's collections: "536 Puzzles & Curious Problems", and trying to track down all the references in his editorial footnotes.

In his discussion of the "Four Fours" problem (Answers section of Puzzle 109 in the above collection), he references the magazine "Recreational Mathematics Magazine", specifically issue 14 from 1964.

I have managed to track down a copy of this specific issue of this magazine on sale via Amazon (although unfortunately not shipping to this locale), and also a copy of Issue 13. Nice and all, but what I am having difficulty tracking down is any publication details of the magazine itself: between what dates was it published, so on and so forth, and particularly (the holy grail) where I might be able to access its contents online -- or at least a list of its contents.

Does anybody have any concrete information on this magazine?

Comment: Wikipedia article on its successor, [Journal of Recreational Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Recreational_Mathematics), lists the dates as from 1961 to 1964. There is another [Recreational Mathematics Magazine](https://sciendo.com/journal/RMM) that has been running since 2016, no relation.

Comment: A reprint of the most popular columns from the original 1961-1964 run is available and in stock on [amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/Alphametics-Expressed-Recreational-Mathematics-Magazine/dp/1508538131/ref=sr_1_1?crid=FC93FAMLCNGG&keywords=Alphametics+as+Expressed+in+Recreational+Mathematics+Magazine&qid=1644991570&sprefix=alphametics+as+expressed+in+recreational+mathematics+magazine%2Caps%2C387&sr=8-1) for a mere $5.23.  It's also available and in stock on amazon's UK site.

Comment: @nwr All I can find is a book containing the cryptarithms only, but I'll carry on looking, thx

Comment: The amazon preview includes a mailing address and email address for the editor who took over after Nelson and Madachy.  Perhaps he can be of help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Joseph Madachy published 14 issues of this title from 1961 to 1964.  In case it helps, I think it has ISSN 0486-1876 and OCLC 1774076.

The [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/recreational-mathematics-magazine/oclc/707441231/) listing shows some volumes in several North American university libraries (and a few other collections, including the New York Public Library and Kansas City's Linda Hall Library) but, elsewhere, only in Utrecht and Adelaide.

It is in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ophVAAAAYAAJ), but only with "snippet" view available because of copyrights.  The [Hathi Trust](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/api/volumes/oclc/1774076.html) also has it but just allows searching.